# Install perl-JSON on centos

Tags: json, perl, centos, centos6

When I'm trying to run a perl script (on my centos 6 machine) I get this message:

```
Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1 .)...
```

After googling a bit, I found out that I need to install that module; But, when I'm typing:

```
sudo yum install perl-JSON
```

I get this message:

```
    ...
Setting up Install Process
Package perl-JSON-2.17-1.el5.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

What can I do in order to run that script?

My perl version is `v5.10.1`

Thanks,

Comment: Interesting, I was missing this module and was looking for a way to install it via yum instead of CPAN and your question answered it (yum install perl-JSON). This sorted it out on my CentOS 7. If CPAN works for you, maybe you could check which path is using.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try to install it via:

1) CPAN ([cpan install](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html))

```
$ sudo cpan JSON
```

2) CPAN minus ([cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm))

Install cpan minus

```
$ wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.5017.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf App-cpanminus-1.5017.tar.gz
$ cd App-cpanminus-1.5017
$ perl make.pl
$ make 
$ make test
$ sudo make install
```

Then install it via cpanm

```
$ sudo cpanm JSON
```

I prefer work with CPAN modules via cpanm, because it's modern and easy way!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this will help others.
In my case,
running in Centos 7:

```
yum install cpan
```

then

```
yum install cpanminus
```

Answer (score 2):

for cpan (not cpan minus):

`yum install cpan
cpan JSON`

Comment: the first line "yum install cpan" is simpler since it gets it from the repo instead of compiling from source code (as in wget/tar/make).
The second line "cpan JSON" is the same as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thw wget/tar/make is for cpanminus, not plain cpan. His `sudo cpan JSON` is assuming you've already got `cpan` installed, true.

Comment: ok, I edited my answer to highlight that it is not for the cpan minus.